# If $G=\mathsf{Aut}_k(F)$ acts on field $F$ algebraic over $k$ then do we have: orbit $G\alpha=\text{ roots of minimal polynomial of }\alpha$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

Let $k\subseteq F$ denote an algebraic field extension and let $\alpha\in F$ having $f\in k[x]$ as its minimal polynomial.

My question:

> If $\beta\in F$ is a root of $f$ then does there exists some $\sigma\in\mathsf{Aut}_k(F)$ with $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta$?

I know that the answer is "yes" if the extension is normal but am puzzling whether this condition is necessary or can be weakened.

Thank you in advance for taking notice of this question, and sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: I thought of three roots, sorry.

Comment: Now crossposted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408276/

Comment: The subject line does not quite match the question: you aren't asking for an automorphism that *switches* the roots (that would also require $\sigma(\beta)=\alpha$), you are asking whether the action is transitive on the roots in $F$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right about the unfortunate title. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/408276/40263) I was attended on that also and there things are edited by now. It is indeed about transitivity of the action on the set of roots (do they form one orbit or more than one?)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Now the titles here and Overflow are the same.

Comment: And you already got an example (twice) on MO, but you commented there disbelieving (or doubting) that it had correctly addressed your question. It did. In the example there, $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, the polynomial $f(x) = x^2-2$ has two roots $\{\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$, both in $F$, but every element of $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(F)$ sends $\sqrt{2}$ to itself (since it must send $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to either $\sqrt[4]{2}$ or to $-\sqrt[4]{2}$, and so must fix the square).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I was worried that my question (with its wrong title) would have been misunderstood because the answers came before the edit of the title. Also I am kind of a "slow thinker". That all must have made the impression of disbelieving or doubting. I think I get it now.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Maybe you noticed already but for certainty let me tell you that my question has been answered on MO now. It might be that the title of my question (now edited) was misleading for you. If so then my excuses for that. Anyhow, I have deleted my former comments adressed to you and will do the same with this comment after a couple of days.